# How to cross-compile C++ file

Tags: c++, linux, cross-compiling

I have installed package for arm cross-compiling

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

If I compile `hello.c` file, it works perfectly

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello.c
```

If I use `hello.cpp` file, it gives error

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello.cpp
```

It shows following error

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

please help me.

Comment: I assume you are on a Debian or Ubuntu system? Please clarify and add the relevant tag to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Install `g++-arm-linux-gnueabi`:

```
sudo apt install -y g++-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

and call `arm-linux-gnueabi-g++` instead:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ hello.cpp
```